# Issue with connecting to NodeJS server - site can’t be reached

Tags: node.js, localhost

I am new to NodeJS and can't connect to the server `http://localhost:6000/`

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json);

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('website'));

const port = 6000;
const server = app.listen(port, listening);
function listening(){
    console.log("localhost port: " + port);
}

app.post('/postdata', (request, response) =>{
    console.log("POST request received!");
});

app.get("/getdata", (request, response) =>{

})
```

**app.js**

```
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    // console.log(data);
        const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', 
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },     
        body: JSON.stringify(data), 
    });

    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        return newData;
    }catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}

postData('/postdata', {Works:456456});
```

[my code with the terminal output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJJUv.png

[browser - can't connect][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K19NS.png

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You don't appear to have a GET route for your root path like so: `app.get('/', (req, res) => return 'Hello World')`. Does adding this fix your problem and display "Hello World"?

Comment: I was using postdata in both the app.js and server.js, the issue was missing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be with missing brackets:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send request to the server without base url.
replace it in this way:

```
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    // console.log(data);
        const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', 
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },     
        body: JSON.stringify(data), 
    });

    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        return newData;
    }catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}

postData('http://localhost:6000/postdata', {Works:456456});
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue was resolved by adding a missing bracket, the base URL is actually working fine
app.use(express.json());